# Build a matrix depending on two random walks in a graph

Tags: r, algorithm, matrix, optimization, igraph

I am working on a project and I reached this point but in fact I am stuck on it since one week ago, I tried many ideas but all trials to code my algorithm failed.

Suppose we have the following simple graph:
[image]

the edges in order are: `1--3`, `1--4`, `3--2`

For each edge, a random walk is defined on each vertex to move to one of it's neighbors like:

For the first edge, `v1=1 ,v2=3, n1=3,4` and `n2=1,2` in order, so the possible moves from v1 and v2 are:

```
1 to 3,3 to 1
1 to 4,3 to 1
1 to 3,3 to 2
1 to 4,3 to 2
```

For the second edge, `v1=1 ,v2=4, n1=3,4` and `n2=1` in order,so the possible moves from v1 and v2 are:

```
1 to 3,4 to 1
1 to 4,3 to 1
```

For the third edge, `v1=3 ,v2=2, n1=1,2` and `n2=3` in order,so the possible moves from v1 and v2 are:

```
3 to 1,2 to 3
3 to 2,2 to 3
```

For the whole graph there are just **8 possible moves** so I have **8 variables to construct the constraints matrix**

Let us denote the moves by x's (according to their order of occurrences); i.e

```
(1 to 3,3 to 1) to be represented by x_1
(1 to 4,3 to 1) to be represented by x_2
                 :
(3 to 1,2 to 3) to be represented by x_7
(3 to 2,2 to 3) to be represented by x_8
```

I want to build the required constraints matrix depending on these moves, the number of constraints will equal `\sum{i} ( number of neighbors for v1(i) * number of neighbors for v2(i) )` which is 10 in our graph.

**My algorithm to build this matrix is:**

```
Step1: 1) select 1st edge, fix v1, v2, n2
       2) change n1 and fill the 1st row of the matrix by 1's in the place of the resulted moves and 0 if there is no similar move on the graph until you finish all elements in n1. 
Step2: move to the 2nd row of the matrix and select the 2nd element of n2 and
       1) loop over n1 
       2) fill the 2nd row by 1's in the place of the resulted moves until you finish all elements in n1. 
Step3: since you selected all elements in n1 and n2 for the vertices in the first edge move to a new row in the matrix 
Step4: Select next edges and do the same work done before until you finish all edges. 
Step5: select the 1st edge again and do the same work but while fixing v1,v2 &n1, loop over n2
```

The resulted matrix according to this algorithm will be:

```
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

**What I failed to do is:** how to let the matrix know that there is a move and to replace it by 1 in it's position and if there is no move to replace it by 0 in it's position

**My code is:**

```
library(igraph)
graph<-matrix(c(1,3,1,4,3,2),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
g<-graph.data.frame(d = graph, directed = FALSE)

countercol<-0
for (edge in 1:length(E(g))){
v1<-ends(graph = g, es = edge)[1]
v2<-ends(graph = g, es = edge)[2]

n1<-neighbors(g,v1,mode=c("all"))
n2<-neighbors(g,v2,mode=c("all"))

countercol=countercol+(length(n1)*length(n2))
}

counterrow<-0
for (edge in 1:length(E(g))){
v1<-ends(graph = g, es = edge)[1]
v2<-ends(graph = g, es = edge)[2]

n1<-neighbors(g,v1,mode=c("all"))
n2<-neighbors(g,v2,mode=c("all"))

counterrow=counterrow+(length(n1)+length(n2))
}    

for (edge in 1:length(E(df))){
v1<-ends(graph = df, es = edge)[1]
v2<-ends(graph = df, es = edge)[2]
n1<-neighbors(df,v1,mode=c("all"))
n2<-neighbors(df,v2,mode=c("all"))
  ...
  ...
  ...
  }
```

I am not looking for someone to write the code, what I want is the idea to  let the program differentiate between the possible moves and store 1's and 0's in the suitable position for the resulted move.

Many Many thanks for any kind of help

Comment: I'm confused what you mean by `v1=1 ,v2=3, n1=3,4` and `n2=1,2`.  `v` means vertice, yes? What does `n` represent?

Comment: How are you defining `n2` in these examples? I don't understand your description of the problem.

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess neighbours

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess v1, v2 are the first and second vertices consequently while n1, n2 are the neighbors (adjacent and connected vertices)  for v1 and v2 consequently

Comment: @MrFlick n2 are the neighbors (connected and adjacent vertices) to v2 which is the second vertex in any edge. The function neighbors(g,edge) determine these neighbors when specifying the vertex

Comment: @MrFlick please feel free to ask about any part confusing you, it will be my pleasure to clarify it

Comment: How come the number of constraints is 10 and not 8? According to your summation it looks like 4+2+2, just like the possible moves. Also, what are these constraints?

Comment: @Julius here the number of variables(are 8 according to the number of col's counter: 2*2+2*1+2*1) but the number of constraints (depending on the number of rows counter are 10: 2+2+2+1+2+1). The number of constraints calculations depends on finding the marginal distribution (\sum_{i}p(x to i, y to j)) & (\sum_{j}p(x to i, y to j)) from the joint distribution (p(x to i, y to j))

Comment: In that case there is a typo in the formula for the number of constraints (i.e., it should be a sum of sums rather than a sum of products). Part 2) of Step1 is not clear.. In particular, "change n1", "resulted moves", "similar move". What is the meaning of the whole matrix? I think it might help to use the terminology of `x_1`, `x_2`, etc. more. And perhaps explaining in detail why one particular matrix cell is 1 or 0, or going over steps 1-3 for a particular edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution consisting of two parts

```
edgeMoves <- function(e) {
  umoves <- sapply(ends(graph = g, es = e), neighbors, graph = g, mode = "all", simplify = FALSE)
  do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(mapply(function(x, y) 
    paste(x, names(y), sep =" to "), ends(graph = g, es = e), umoves, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)), sep = ", "))
}
edgeConstraints <- function(e) {
  v <- ends(graph = g, es = e)
  n1 <- names(neighbors(g, v[1], mode = "all"))
  n2 <- names(neighbors(g, v[2], mode = "all"))
  t(cbind(sapply(n2, function(nn2) moves %in% paste0(v[1], " to ", n1, ", ", v[2], " to ", nn2)),
          sapply(n1, function(nn1) moves %in% paste0(v[1], " to ", nn1, ", ", v[2], " to ", n2))))
}
moves <- do.call(c, sapply(E(g), edgeMoves))
moves
# [1] "1 to 3, 3 to 1" "1 to 4, 3 to 1" "1 to 3, 3 to 2"
# [4] "1 to 4, 3 to 2" "1 to 3, 4 to 1" "1 to 4, 4 to 1"
# [7] "3 to 1, 2 to 3" "3 to 2, 2 to 3"

do.call(rbind, sapply(E(g), edgeConstraints)) * 1
#   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# 1    1    1    0    0    0    0    0    0
# 2    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0
# 3    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
# 4    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0
# 1    0    0    0    0    1    1    0    0
# 3    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
# 4    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
# 3    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    1
# 1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0
# 2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

The row order is different, but I suspect that it is not a problem. Also, for a single edge you may use `edgeMoves(e)` and `edgeConstraints(e) * 1`.

Comment: @user8003788, let me know if I should add any explanations

Comment: Thanks for this nice code, In fact I wrote something but it is more complicated!! I will understand your code and if there is something strange I will ask..thanks again

Comment: Thanks again for this great help, it is working very well but I am following it and trying to understand how it could be possible to let it work on each edge alone(i.e to build the resulted matrix from only an edge not all edges together)?

Comment: The second question is how could I know that the firs 1 in your resulted matrix is related to the first move (1 to 3,3 to 1)? i.e I don't understand how you indexed the moves ? for example if I want to know what is the move represented by one in the first row and column, what I call? and thanks in advance

Comment: @user8003788, see the update regarding the first request. I didn't create any indices. They are implicitly given by the order of a move in the vector `moves` (see the part with `moves %in%`). For instance, if you see ones in columns 2 and 4, you may get the corresponding moves with `moves[c(2, 4)]`.

Comment: thanks again for cooperation. I don't understand what is nn2 and nn1 and where you defined them. Also, i can't see how it work for each edge alone (i. mean to construct the edge constraints fro each edge in a loop on edges) although I used edgeMoves(e) & edgeConstraints(e) * 1 so I would be very grateful if you helped me on this

Comment: @user8003788, `nn2` and `nn1` are arguments of the anonymous (i.e., without a name) functions defined inside of `sapply`. In `sapply` I iterate over sets of neighbours `n1` and `n2`, and `nn1` and `nn2` are corresponding elements from them.

Comment: For a given edge, in `edgeMoves` I first get a list of neighbours for each end of the edge. Then in the second line I use those neighbours to construct all possible combinations of moves. In `edgeConstraints` I again get the ends and their neighbours first. Then by fixing an element from `n1` (`n2`) I construct moves with all the elements of `n2` (`n1`) and use their order in `moves` to construct a binary matrix. It’s not a blackbox, take `e <- E(g)[1]` and go over the code line by line to see what happens.

Comment: Yes this is what I did and it didn't work. It keep producing the moves and constraints matrix for all edges while I was trying to iterate this code on all edges to produce (the possible moves and the constraints matrix) for each edge

Comment: @user8003788, `edgeMoves` returns moves given an edge, `edgeConstraints` returns a matrix given an edge and looking at a vector `moves`. So, for instance, `e <- E(g)[1]; moves <- edgeMoves(e); edgeConstraints(e)` works.